# Is there a way to use the functions inside a component or shared file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-redux, sdk

I'm trying to access functions inside a class based component which can be used throughout the project. The reason I'm thinking class based is because these request/ functions require an init() method to be called before accessing such data **every time**. For example:

SharedSDKFile .js

```
import Facebook from 'facebook-sdk';

class SharedSDKFile extends Component {
   constructor() {
      Facebook.init({// init some stuff})
   }

  async user() {
    return Facebook.getUser()
  }

  render() {
    return(// ????????????????)
  }
}

// *****************************************************
Dashboard.js
// *****************************************************
import Facebook from '../{path}/SharedSDKFile'

const dashboard = () => {
   let [person,setPerson] = useState()

// cool function to get and set Users
   let user = getUser();
   setPerson(user)
// End of cool function

}
```

I even tried structuring it with a different approach just exporting functions

SharedSDKFile.js

```
async init() {
  // init stuff
}

export const getUser = async(data) => {
   init()
   // get user
}

// *****************************************************
Dashboard.js
// *****************************************************
import {getUser}from '../{path}/SharedSDKFile'

const dashboard = () => {
 let [person,setPerson] = useState()

// cool function to get and set Users
   let user = getUser();
   setPerson(user)
// End of cool function
}
```

While a file that exports your function works, the state disappears on reload/ refresh.

Perhaps there is a better solution to this and I'm overthinking it. I have considered redux or localstate, but I will have several functions inside the sharedSDKFile.js which will require several action and reducers...

I am trying to prevent invoking multiple init() and redundancy if I am to import, for example, the FacebookSDK in every file that needs it.

Comment: why dont you use hooks?

Comment: You say "these...require an init() method to be called...every time", but then say "I am trying to prevent invoking multiple init()". Do you want the init called once, or every time it's used?

Comment: @RafaelMora when you refer to use hooks, can you be more specific? use what function/ method exactly and how?

Comment: @Jayce444 good catch, to clarify, the init must be called every time a method is being used or called

Comment: @Invisible-coder you can use `React.useEffect(()=>{initfunc(); return()=>{}},[])` in order to call any function on component loading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using a context singleton approach to isolate external services that can be used app-wide, which may or may not suit what you want to do. It uses context providers/consumers rather than things like Redux.

This isn't the complete picture but hopefully it provides some idea of how the approach might work for you:

**FacebookContext.js (or AWSContext.js, or... any specific service)**

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
import Facebook from "facebook-sdk";

export const FacebookContext = createContext({});

class FacebookProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    user: null,
    // whatever else you need to expose to calling components, like
    // lastLoggedIn: null,
    // verified: false,
    // ...
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Facebook.init({
      // init some stuff
    })
  }

  setUser = user => {
    this.setState({
      user
    });
  }

  // whatever other methods/data you want this class to expose

  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookContext.Provider
        value={{
          user: this.state.user // available with FacebookContext.user
          // other state values
          //
          setUser: this.setUser // available with FacebookContext.setUser
          // other class methods
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </FacebookContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default FacebookProvider;
```

**Add the Provider to your top-line app file, something like this in e.g. App.js:**

```
import FacebookProvider from "/path/to/FacebookContext";

// ...

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookProvider>
        {yourAppRenderStuff}
      </FacebookProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Add the Consumer to any calling components:**

```
import { FacebookContext } from "/path/to/FacebookContext";

class SomethingComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { facebookContext } = this.props;

    facebookContext.setUser(`some user`);// available in other components

    console.log(facebookContext.user);// broadcasted to other components
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <></>
    );
  }
}

const Something = () => (
  <FacebookContext.Consumer>
    {facebookContext => (
      <SomethingComponent facebookContext={facebookContext} />
    )}
  </FacebookContext.Consumer>
);

export default Something;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This definitely was another alternative I am going to consider and it's easier to implement. Thank you!